# Font doesn't get loaded through webpack

Tags: css, fonts, webpack, webpack-2

Hello dear webpack community.
I desperately try to load fonts using the file-loader
I tried both of these rules:

```
{ test: /\.(woff|eot|svg|otf|ttf)$/i, loader: `file-loader`, options: {name:'fonts/[name].[ext]'}},
{ test: /\.(woff|eot|svg|otf|ttf)$/i, loader: `file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]`},
```

however, unfortunately, the fonts don't get pulled when asked for them in the @font-face rule:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Example';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('../fonts/Example.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

This is how my project structure looks like:

[image: structure]

This is the Webpack output:

[image: webpack output]

While fonts.less is loaded, I don't see any font getting loaded through the definition of src().

Thank you a lot for any hint in advance!

See the full config file here: https://gist.github.com/MartinMuzatko/2873b52fed204bd6e8aaaa94527e34a9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `raw-loader` to transform the output of the `less-loader` to JavaScript so that `extract-text-webpack-plugin` can use it.

```
{
    test: /\.less$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
        [
            {loader:'raw'},
            {loader:'less'}
        ]
    ),
}
```

The `less-loader` simply transforms the Less syntax to regular CSS. The `url()` won't be touched. The [`css-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#options) on the other hand treats them as imports that webpack will resolve. Only then your rules for the fonts will take effect. All you need to do is change your `.less` rule to use `css-loader` instead of `raw-loader`:

```
{
    test: /\.less$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
        [
            {loader:'css'},
            {loader:'less'}
        ]
    ),
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Of course! This is what the css-loader does. thank you so much :)